# How to compile pdf in Overleaf not from scratch each time?

Tags: pdf, compiling, overleaf

I am compiling a pdf in Overleaf but even if there is a minor change, the pdf will be compiled from scratch and that will take a while for a large document. How to avoid this? Is there an option to specify a setting so that only a part that was modified will be changed in the pdf?

Comment: Unfortunately, the way LaTeX works requires that the full document needs to be compiled from scratch every time, so there is no setting to change this. There are some tricks, for example if you work on a document with different chapters then you can put each chapter in a separate file and compile only the current chapter (and put everything together in the end when you are finished writing the full document). If you have large complicated graphics (for example made with TikZ or pgfplots) then you can externalize them to make sure they are compiled only if the image code has changed.

Comment: Additionally having, say, chapters in separate files and inputtet via `\include` then enables you to use the `\includeonly{file1,file2,....}` feature to only load the chapter you are currently working on. The long compilation duration are often down to complicated tikz images as Marijn mentions or lots of tables formatted via `siunitx` (the latter can be speed up a lot via setting the `siunitx` number parsing globally to false while you're working on the document)